Custom Line Number/Prefix for text file using awk/sed
Before raising the flag I tried couple of things but didn't get the desired result.
I have many text files which I want prefixed with custom numbering;
   the first 2 lines should be prefixed  00A:  , 00B:  
   and remaining lines should be incremental, like 001:  ,002:  ,003:  , and so on

Presently, I use  this command for incremental numbering
awk '{printf("%03d:  %s\r\n", NR,$0)}' file1.txt > file2.txt

*which does the incremental nos. ok for the whole file; but not the multiple types needed.
Example Input file:
136725A6449C5279 933FB466C9CD699B
8FFBBA87E9D3209A AB41FBDC5E281A92
FF80DA7B0054FB29 006BF1C82C75C341
FA118264221B02A7 81E9A1FEB75FFB3D
31AA9FC566C3ADE0 70DDFD6DED2BF29C
F0B39014DA7FA6B1 77401108A81E33E1
74EF54060BC2B72F B5518D896DDC266F
DE10C97F9FBDA5A6 6C79566CA1BDC06E

Desired Output:
00A:  136725A6449C5279 933FB466C9CD699B
00B:  8FFBBA87E9D3209A AB41FBDC5E281A92
001:  FA118264221B02A7 81E9A1FEB75FFB3D
002:  31AA9FC566C3ADE0 70DDFD6DED2BF29C
003:  F0B39014DA7FA6B1 77401108A81E33E1
004:  74EF54060BC2B72F B5518D896DDC266F
005:  DE10C97F9FBDA5A6 6C79566CA1BDC06E


Neither Awk nor sed does this very well, but Perl has it built in.
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $prefix = "A"; }
  $prefix = "1" if ($. == 3);
  printf "%03s:  ", $prefix++;' file

The crucial feature here is that in Perl, "A"++ produces "B", natively. It doesn't work so well with leading zeros, though; so I resorted to padding here.
Your question is rather unclear as to what should happen after 00Z or after 009 so I had to guess.  For what it's worth, in Perl, "Z"++ is "AA".
If you really insist on an Awk solution, it can be done with something like this:
awk '{ printf("%03s:  %s\n", (NR == 1 ? "A" : \
    (NR == 2 ? "B" : NR-2)), $0)}' file

I took out the fugly \r; if you are on Windows, maybe put it back (or consider your options).
As noted in comments, this works on MacOS / nawk but might not on other Awks.

by the way, i used the awk command suggested; perl isnt something i am familiar with

Perl is a completely different language but it has some design features which make a subset of it fairly familiar to Awk or sed users. These days, I'd expect to find it installed most everywhere, perhaps save for stripped down Docker images or embedded systems. But fair enough; I find myself preferring Awk for the small stuff and Python for the bigger stuff after many years in Perl land.

What awk are you using? %03s seems to not work on my gawk and mawk, only on nawk (original awk).

I tested this on MacOS, I guess that means "the One True Awk"

@tripleee Curious, is this awk 'BEGIN{print 1 == 2 ? 3 : 4}' still failing on your awk?

@AndreWildberg Yes, it gives me a syntax error after 1

@tripleee Thx, so mac's still using the old nawk/oawk base versus gawk and mawk, which have more in common nowadays.

i am using macOS 11

%03 only pads with leading zeros for numbers, not strings, so don't expect %03s to pad with 0s.

@AndreWildberg always parenthesize your ternary expressions for clarity and that also deals with this particular (fairly frequently reported on MacOS at least) problem, i.e. use awk 'BEGIN{print (1 == 2 ? 3 : 4)}'

Regarding "Neither Awk nor sed does this very well" - agreed on sed but I'd argue that awk does it pretty well.

@EdMorton Usually do. Just took this as a test to get the state of Mac awk. But maybe you want to add this to your answer then https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699842/gnu-awk-traditional-vs-posix ;)

@EdMorton I mean the general case of "incrementing" a string. All the solutions here work fine for  A through Z but don't generalize very well from there.

You mean to make "Z"++ become "AA", for example? Yeah, you would have to implement a little loop to do that in awk since in awk doing any arithmetic operation using a string converts the string to a number first and then the result is a number and trying to pre/post increment a literal string would be a syntax error, just like trying to pre/post increment a literal number.

Well Ruby can do this too: s="A"; s.next

With any POSIX awk:
awk '{s = NR>2 ? sprintf("%03d",NR-2) : "00" substr("AB",NR,1); print s ":  " $0}'


Using any awk:
$ awk -v OFS=':  ' '{print ( NR<3 ? sprintf("00%c",NR+64) : sprintf("%03d",NR-2) ), $0}' file
00A:  136725A6449C5279 933FB466C9CD699B
00B:  8FFBBA87E9D3209A AB41FBDC5E281A92
001:  FF80DA7B0054FB29 006BF1C82C75C341
002:  FA118264221B02A7 81E9A1FEB75FFB3D
003:  31AA9FC566C3ADE0 70DDFD6DED2BF29C
004:  F0B39014DA7FA6B1 77401108A81E33E1
005:  74EF54060BC2B72F B5518D896DDC266F
006:  DE10C97F9FBDA5A6 6C79566CA1BDC06E

Alternatively, inspired by @glennjackman's comment:
$ awk '{if (NR<3) {f="X"; v=9} else {f="d"; v=-2} printf "%03"f":  %s\n", NR+v, $0}' file
00A:  136725A6449C5279 933FB466C9CD699B
00B:  8FFBBA87E9D3209A AB41FBDC5E281A92
001:  FF80DA7B0054FB29 006BF1C82C75C341
002:  FA118264221B02A7 81E9A1FEB75FFB3D
003:  31AA9FC566C3ADE0 70DDFD6DED2BF29C
004:  F0B39014DA7FA6B1 77401108A81E33E1
005:  74EF54060BC2B72F B5518D896DDC266F
006:  DE10C97F9FBDA5A6 6C79566CA1BDC06E


Alternately: NR<3 ? sprint("%03X", NR + 9) : ...

@glennjackman good idea, I updated my answer to add a variant based on that.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
Able
Baker
Charlie
Dog

then
awk -v prefixes="00A 00B" 'BEGIN{split(prefixes,arr)}{prefix=(NR in arr)?arr[NR]:sprintf("%03d",++i);print prefix ":  " $0}' file.txt

gives output
00A:  Able
00B:  Baker
001:  Charlie
002:  Dog

Explanation: I set prefixes variable to space-sheared list of prefixes, then in begin I fill arr array with in context. For each line I check if there is prefix in array for given line, if so I use them, otherwise I use sprintf to create prefix from preincremented i variable, then I print concatenation of prefix, desired separator and given line. This solution will automatically adjust to any number of prefixes, e.g. if you wish 00A 00B 00C then it is enough to set prefixes to 00A 00B 00C.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Similar to Perl, Ruby has the concept of a next in a sequence. The next after "A" is "B" and the next after 1 is 2 and so on.
This Ruby:
ruby -lne 'BEGIN{ln="A"}
# replace "3" in .rjust(3,"0") with appropriate column width:
puts "#{ln.to_s.rjust(3,"0")}:\t#{$_}" 
ln= ($.==2) ? 1 : ln.next
' file 

Prints:
00A:    136725A6449C5279 933FB466C9CD699B
00B:    8FFBBA87E9D3209A AB41FBDC5E281A92
001:    FF80DA7B0054FB29 006BF1C82C75C341
002:    FA118264221B02A7 81E9A1FEB75FFB3D
003:    31AA9FC566C3ADE0 70DDFD6DED2BF29C
004:    F0B39014DA7FA6B1 77401108A81E33E1
005:    74EF54060BC2B72F B5518D896DDC266F
006:    DE10C97F9FBDA5A6 6C79566CA1BDC06E

That could be enhanced to adjust the width of the line number column to the width of the max number of lines. The requires user input or reading the file twice.
